# Ignore certain links in the html magnific-popup

Tags: magnific-popup

I need Magnific-popup to bind to only certain links in the HTML. This is so when one linked is clicked it will link out to another website. If the other link is clicked it will enlarge the image.

Right now the link the being clicked that is not wrapped in an image the popup is initialized.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="field__item">
    <div class="mfp-field mfp-separate-item">
      <a href="path-to-origin-image">
        <!-- This link is being added to the popup and works correctly-->
        <img class="mfp-thumbnail" src="img-url" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="field--name-field-url">
      <!-- This link is being added to the popup and should be ignored -->
      <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery

```
 $(context).find('.field--name-field-gallery-items').once('mfp-processed').each( function() {
        $(this).magnificPopup({
          delegate: 'a',
          type: 'image',
          gallery: {
            enabled: true
          },
          image: {
            titleSrc: function (item) {
              return item.img.attr('alt') || '';
            }
          }
        });
      });

      $(context).find('.field--name-field-gallery-items .field--name-field-url a').each().unbind('click');
```

How do I stop magnificPopup from binding to the second link?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the following:

```
$(context).find('.field--name-field-gallery-items').once('mfp-processed').each( function() {
        $(this).magnificPopup({
          delegate: '.mfp-field a',
          type: 'image',
          gallery: {
            enabled: true
          },
          image: {
            titleSrc: function (item) {
              return item.img.attr('alt') || '';
            }
          }
        });
      });
```

I should have read the api properly